# xargs treat multiple lines as arguments to single command invocation

Tags: bash, command, xargs

I am having a hard time print a seq of number, and then appending something at the end.

```
seq 1 3 | xargs -I {} echo {} 4
```

results in

```
1 4
2 4
3 4
```

However I want the result to be

```
1 2 3 4
```

Since I am learning `xargs`, I only want to use `xargs` to achieve this.

Comment: @don_crissti - amazing ! Thanks.. what is this bang in the end? Without it , it doesnt work. If you write this as an answer, then will accept it

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to pass a certain number of lines as arguments to a single invocation of `command` via GNU `xargs` you would run something like:

```
multi-line cmd | xargs -d '\n' -n N command
```

i.e. use `\n` as delimiter and pass `N` lines<sup>1</sup> at a time to `command` which would be the equivalent of running

```
command line1 line2 ... lineN
```

Now, `xargs` operates like this:

```
input | xargs [options] [command [initial-arguments]]
```

which means whatever arguments `xargs` adds to your command line when building it up, they will come after the initial-arguments of `command` so e.g.

```
multi-line cmd | xargs -d '\n' -n N command initial-args
```

will execute

```
command initial-args line1 line2 ... lineN
```

which is why you won't be able to run

```
seq 1 3 | xargs -d '\n' -n 3 echo 4
```

and get the expected output because `4` will be considered as initial-argument and the end result will be

`4 1 2 3`

What you could do is invoke a `sh`ell to run `command` - that will enable you to position any additional arguments at the end:

```
seq 1 3 | xargs -d '\n' -n 3 sh -c 'echo "$@" 4' bang
```

```
1 2 3 4
```

---

What is `bang` in the above one-liner? `sh -c` [syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) is

```
sh -c command_string [command_name [argument...]]
```

so  `'echo "$@" 4'` is the `command_string` (`$@` expands to the positional parameters, in this case the ones added by `xargs`) and `bang` is the special parameter `0`, the `command_name` (you can use any name e.g. `sh`)
Worth reading: [Why $0 is not a positional parameter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412707)

---

Note that my post pertains to GNU `xargs` and its exclusive `-d` switch. Alternatively, you could do it in shell, saving the output lines into an array and passing its elements as arguments to `command` before any additional arguments, so
e.g. with `bash`

```
readarray -t args < <(multi-line cmd)
command "${args[@]}" additional-arg(s)
```

or with `zsh`

```
args=("${(@f)$(multi-line cmd)}")
command "${args[@]}" additional-arg(s)
```

---

<sup>1: assuming those `N` lines fall within `ARG_MAX` limits</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Changing some lines into a single line is done with `paste -s`.

In this case, you want to change four lines into a single line.
The four lines are created with `seq 1 3; echo 4`:

```bash
$ seq 1 3; echo 4
1
2
3
4
```

Pass these through `paste -d ' ' -s -` to convert them into a single line, delimiting each original line with a space character:

```bash
$ { seq 1 3; echo 4; } | paste -d ' ' -s -
1 2 3 4
```

You could pass the lines through `tr '\n' ' '` instead of through `paste -s`, but this would also replace the final newline character with a space (the one after `4`), which is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The xargs part is fine. The seq can take a separator like so

```
seq -s ' ' 1 3 | xargs -I {} echo {} 4
```

Comment: That's not making `xargs` use one process on all inputs. You simply make it so that you only have one input, basically cheating the problem. That's not an answer to the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

On BSDs, that's what the `-J` option is for:

```
$ seq 3 | xargs -J {} echo {} 4
1 2 3 4
```

In any case, `xargs` will still call the command multiple times if the list of arguments is so big that it won't fit within the `execve()` limit.

With other `xargs` implementations, as already said you can get `sh` to reorder the arguments:

```
$ seq 3 | xargs sh -c 'echo "$@" 4' sh
1 2 3 4
```

With `xargs` implementations that don't support the `-r` option, you can also leverage `sh` to check that at least one argument was passed:

```
cmd1 | xargs sh -c '[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec cmd2 "$@" additional args' sh
```

Note the `exec` that saves a fork in shell implementations that don't do that optimisation automatically. For builtin commands such as `echo`, in some `sh` implementations such as bash, using `exec` causes the *external* command (if available) to be called instead of the builtin one, making it behave more like when `sh` is not used (`xargs cmd2`).